# vertical menu navigation with jquery (closing toggle)

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation

I have my vertical navigation working great with jQuery. It matches the URL, so it remains open on a dynamic site without cookies being required. This is my current fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/J8HnC/

The jQuery that I'm using now is this:

```
jQuery('#categories .sub').not('.open').children('ul').hide();

jQuery(document).on('click', '#category-menu #categories button', function(){

    $(this).parent().addClass('expandable');

    if(jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('expandable')) {
        jQuery(this).html('+');
        jQuery(this).siblings('ul').stop(true,true).css('display','block').slideDown(200, 'linear');
    } else {
        jQuery(this).siblings('ul').stop(true,true).css('display','none').slideUp(200, 'linear');
    };

});

var url = window.location.toString() 

$('#categories ul li a').each(function(){

    var categoryHref= $(this).attr('href');

    if( url.match(categoryHref)) {
        $(this).addClass('active-anchor')
        $(this).parents('ul.category-child').show();
        $(this).parents('ul.category-child li').addClass('expandable');
    }

});
```

But I can't work out the logic to close the menu items properly in my jQuery. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: i think you can add a variable to see if the menu is open, and if open then on click remove the classes that you added (expendable)

Comment: ...thank you for reply btevik! much appreciated...i'm brain fried at the moment, jquery not my strongest point...unsure how to invoke the variable idea brought forward...

Answer (score 1):

this should get you started.

add `value="1"` to each `button` in page.

then get the value and if it is equal to `1`, basically open the menu. (what you have right now)

then set the value to `0`.

if the value is `0`, undo what you did. then set value to `1`.

http://jsfiddle.net/J8HnC/2/

Comment: ...thank you btevfik! this looks to be working much better, soooooooo close!! I have tested in my dynamic site locally, i put the default value of "1" on my button, so now all buttons have that value when page loads...the problem i am seeing is that when i click on a sub-category lower down the menu, page reloads, menu remains open (which is great!), but to collapse the menu items above on the buttons (that are expanded because URL matching), it takes two clicks before the menu items above the active category will close....this is my current fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J8HnC/11/

Comment: oh yeah. since when you reload the value gets reset, it will have that behavior. i guess you have to save it in a cookie and retrieve it. or you have to add additional info on your url.

Comment: actually i think you can check if it has the `expendable` class with http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/ if it has than set the value to 0 on page load.

Comment: ....hi btevfik! it is definitely because the <li> blocks above in the tree don't have the class "expandable" when the page reloads, so first click adds the class, the second click removes the class at the moment...thank you sooo much for the help! hasClass looks interesting approach...

Comment: ...i think i  need to somehow

Comment: (...oops, hit return early!)...i think i need to somehow reset the value to "0" on the button, if the <li> block above doesn't have the class "expandable"...

Comment: ...no...i have pretty well given up too now...bit soul destroying this.